# on link hover add/remove css class to image

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add and remove class on hover the link to the image above it (inside the same container) but I am missing something because it doesn't work:

This is the snippet in jQuery:

```
jQuery('.category-view a').hover(
  function () {
    jQuery(this).parent('img').removeClass('nzi');
  },
  function () {

    jQuery(this).parent('img').addClass('nzi');
  }
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="category-view">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="category floatleft width33 vertical-separator " style="margin:50px;">
            <div class="spacer">
                <img src="/harbini/images/stories/virtuemart/category/resized/lips_202x296.png" alt="lips">                     
                <h2 class="catSub"> <a href="/harbini/index.php/al/produktet/grim/buzet" title="Buzët"> Buzët </a> </h2>

                <a href="/harbini/index.php/al/produktet/grim/buzet" class="category-overlay"><span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="category floatleft width33 " style="margin:50px;">
            <div class="spacer">
                <img src="/harbini/images/stories/virtuemart/category/resized/face_202x296.png" alt="face.png">                     
                <h2 class="catSub"> <a href="/harbini/index.php/al/produktet/grim/fytyra" title="Fytyra"> Fytyra </a> </h2>

                <a href="/harbini/index.php/al/produktet/grim/fytyra" class="category-overlay"><span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="horizontal-separator"></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="category floatleft width33 vertical-separator " style="margin:50px;">
            <div class="spacer">
                <img src="/harbini/images/stories/virtuemart/category/resized/eyes_202x296.png" alt="eyes">                     
                <h2 class="catSub"> <a href="/harbini/index.php/al/produktet/grim/syte" title="Sytë"> Sytë </a> </h2>

                <a href="/harbini/index.php/al/produktet/grim/syte" class="category-overlay"><span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="category floatleft width33  " style="margin:50px;">
            <div class="spacer">
                <img src="/harbini/images/stories/virtuemart/category/resized/nails_202x296.png" alt="nails.png">                       
                <h2 class="catSub"> <a href="/harbini/index.php/al/produktet/grim/thonjte" title="Thonjtë"> Thonjtë </a> </h2>

                <a href="/harbini/index.php/al/produktet/grim/thonjte" class="category-overlay"><span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The images aren't parents of the anchors, they're siblings.

Comment: please create a fiddle for better understand by visually

Comment: i've checked the code you have two anchor links one is child and another is sibling to image so let us know on which anchor link you want to run function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `img` is not a parent of the `a` element, it is a sibling element, so use [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
jQuery('.category-view a').hover(
  function () {
    jQuery(this).siblings('img').removeClass('nzi');
  },
  function () {
    jQuery(this).siblings('img').addClass('nzi');
  }
```

But since there are two `a` elements (one inside `h2`)

```
jQuery('.category-view a').hover(
    function () {
        jQuery(this).closest('.category').find('img').removeClass('nzi');
    },
    function () {
        jQuery(this).closest('.category').find('img').addClass('nzi');
    }
);
```

Comment: you haven't seen it has two anchor tag one is child and another is sibling.

Comment: @TheMechanic post that I'd edited the answer... it will be helpful to the user if the downvoter can leave a comment saying what is missed so that it can be rectified